# (Python/Pyramid) Better ways to have standard list/form editors?

Tags: python, forms, helper, pyramid

I'm working on a number of Pyramid (former Pylons) projects, and often I have the need to display a list of some content (let's say user accounts, log entries or simply some other data). A user should be able to paginate through the list, click on a row and get a form where he/she can edit the contents of that row.

Right now I'm always re-inventing the wheel by having Mako templates which use *webhelpers* for the pagination, Jquery UI for providing a dialog and I craft the editor form and AJAX requests on the client and server side by hand.

As you may know, this eats up painfully much time. 
So what I'm wondering is: Is there a better way of providing lists, editor dialog and server/client communication about this, without having to re-invent the wheel every time?

I heard Django takes off a big load of that by providing user accounts and other stuff out of the box; but in my case it's not just about user accounts, it can be any kind of data that is stored on the server-side in a SQL database, which should be able to be edited by a user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

is this what youre looking for?

pypi --> http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_formalchemy

docs --> http://docs.formalchemy.org/pyramid_formalchemy/

demo!! --> http://demo.formalchemy.org/

code --> https://github.com/FormAlchemy/pyramid_formalchemy and https://github.com/FormAlchemy/fa.jquery

Note:

- only works with SQLA, I think
- you have to work on authn/authz/permission yourself
- you can use fa.jquery with it

I tried this few hours ago, the package from pypi is broken ( https://github.com/FormAlchemy/pyramid_formalchemy/issues/11 ), so you might want to source install/develop

Comment: I'll take a look at it as soon as I'm back home. :)